# Runtime options for firebase Cloud Functions V2 onDocumentDeleted

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm using Firebase Cloud Functions V2 and in the case of **CALLABLE** functions I'm able to set runtime options as such:

```
exports.myCloudFunction = onCall(
    {
        cors: [
            "https://www.myWebsite.com",
            "https://www.myWebsite.com.br"
        ],
        region: "southamerica-east1",
        enforceAppCheck: true,
        minInstances: 1,
        memory: "1GB",
        concurrency: 1,
        timeoutSeconds: 540
    },
    async (request) => {
        try {
            if (request.app == undefined) {
                throw new functions.https.HttpsError('failed-precondition', 'The function must be called from a verified app');
            }
            if (!request.auth || !request.auth.uid) {
                throw new functions.https.HttpsError('unauthenticated', 'User is not logged in');
            }
        } catch (error) {
            // Error handling
        }
    }
)
```

BUT with **TRIGGER** cloud functions, the documentation points to two versions of onDocumentDeleted:
[1]: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/2nd-gen/node/firebase-functions.firestore.md

But even in the one where the first function parameter is DocumentOptions, those options do not include runtime options, only document based parameters:
[2]: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/2nd-gen/node/firebase-functions.firestore.documentoptions.md#firestoredocumentoptions_interface

The current code for the **TRIGGER** function deletes group messages from a collection recursively like this:

```
exports.triggerFunction = onDocumentDeleted(`groups/{deletedGroupUID}`, async (event) => {
    try {
        const snapshot = event.data;
        const deletedDocUID = snapshot.id;
        const deletedDocData = snapshot.data();
        
        const chatsCollectionRef = admin.firestore().collection("chats").doc(deletedDocUID).collection("chatRoom");
        async function deleteDocumentsInBatch(collectionRef) {
            const querySnapshot = await collectionRef.limit(300).get();

            if (querySnapshot.size <= 0) return;

            let deletionOperations = [];
            querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
                if (!doc.exists) return;
                const deleteDocOperation = doc.ref.delete();
                deletionOperations.push(deleteDocOperation);
            });
            await Promise.all(deletionOperations);

            // Recursively delete the next batch of documents
            return deleteDocumentsInBatch(collectionRef);
        }
        await deleteDocumentsInBatch(chatsCollectionRef);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error on triggerFunction", error);
    }
});
```

How should I configure the runtime options for Firebase trigger Cloud Functions ? didn't find any official documentation for that.

Comment: You missed an important detail in the DocumentOptions interface documentation that you linked to.  If you read it carefully, you'll see that DocumentOptions extends EventHandlerOptions.  This means that a DocumentOptions object can also specify (in the same object) some of the configuration parameters you're looking for in EventHandlerOptions. Note also that EventHandlerOptions extends GlobalOptions, which has more options you're looking for, again all in the same object.

Comment: That's great @DougStevenson, thank you for making it clear.

Comment: @DougStevenson you saved me :)


export const function = onDocumentWritten({
  document: documentPath,
  memory: '512MiB',
...other options
}, (event) => {